# How to split strings

Tags: javascript

I have tried `Split("?")` and `Split('?')`. Both give the same error  (`link.split` is not a function), so i assume that there is a way to be able to split but not using this `Split`?
Maybe jQuery?

*Edit*: Got it, it should be `href.split`. So as jordan said, it was not a string. So i used `x.href.split("?")` and it   worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetpack just uses JavaScript so this should work:

```
var str = "My.string";
str.split("."); // => [ "My", "string" ]
```

If it tells you "split is not a function" then it probably means your variable doesn't hold a string like you think it does.

Comment: Alright , Thanks alot .

My value actually is a href  
  var link= doc.querySelector('#courses_menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) a');
Then i try to split it by "?"

anyhelp ?

Comment: Okay, that's useful, then. doc.querySelector() returns an element object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element and it looks like the most reliable way to get an attribute (like 'href') would be element.getAttribute('href'). That should return your URL string that you can then split.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not already a string, convert it first.

```
myObject.toString().split("?");
```

Comment: That would be a good idea  . Thanks 
however i used links.href.split("?"); 
and worked allright